# Enable Expert Settings in Visual C++ Express 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I really can't find the way to enable the Expert Settings in Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition! I need to access the command console and others!

I've searched through several questions and sites, but none offers the correct answers

[This is for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852994/visual-studio-2012-expert-mode)

Comment: Express editions have usually some limitations, so you have a reason to buy the product. "Expert settings" sound like a reason for a professional product.

Comment: I used to enable `Expert Settings` in my earlier versions of visual studios, all are express editions.. microsoft hide the expert settings since 2008 (or 2010) to simplify the ui for beginners or c# and visual basic programmers I think...

Comment: How do you display the hidden settings?

Comment: in VS2010? it is stated in the link: `This is for Visual Studio 2010`

Comment: this might help others: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17754326/843000 note View> Other Windows> Property Manager

Comment: @Zennichimaro: I think you posted the wrong "This is for Visual Studio 2010" link. It points to an unanswered 2012 question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about Visual Studio 2012, expert mode has been dropped so that power user like us will buy the professional edition.

Your solutions and projects for VS2012 still open and work the same in VS2010, so you can still download Visual Studio 2010 Express and use it to open and work on Visual Studio 2012 Solutions